# How to populate data in jquery data table without making ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using jquery data table plugin to populate data in web table using ajax.But i want to populate data by calling a method which is present in js file without making ajax call.Is there any way?

Sharing my code.

```
 ajax : $.fn.dataTable.pipelineAdv({
            url : oMapUrls.loadDefaultMap,
            pages : !bLivePaginate ? -1 : Global.pageSize,
            method : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            data : function() {
                var requestData = {
                    serverSide : false
                };
                if (bTimeFiltered) {
                    requestData.withInTime = iFilterByTime;
                }
                if (sFilteredVehicleIds) {
                    requestData.vehicleIds = sFilteredVehicleIds;
                }
                return requestData;
            },
            redraw : function() {
                return (getPageName() === "map");
            },
            callback : function(oJSON, request) {
                aLiveFleetData = oJSON.serverResponse.result;
                if (mapRefreshTimer) {
                    window.clearTimeout(mapRefreshTimer);
                }
                setMapRefreshTimer();
            }
        }),
        oCustomization : {
            sExportFunctionCall : oMapUrls.exportLiveFleetReport,
            bAdvanceExport : true,
            bShowDefaultAll : !bLivePaginate
        },
        pageLength : !bLivePaginate ? -1 : Global.rowLength,
        scrollCollapse : false,
        scrollY : iDataTableHeight,
        serverSide : bLivePaginate,
        order : [ [ 3, "desc" ] ],
        columns : [
                {
                    "data" : "trackeeName",
                    "width" : aColumnWidths[0],
                    "class" : "no-word-break",
                    "settings" : {
                        source : function(request, oCallback) {
                            oCallback($.ui.autocomplete.filter(Global.aJSTreeVehicleItems || [], request.term));
                        }
                    },
                    "title" : jQuery.i18n.prop("report.columnTitle.vehicle"),
                    "render" : function(value, type, rowData) {
                        if (type == "display") {
                            rowData.formattedDate = Global.getTimeStampToDate(rowData.dateAndTime, rowData.offset,
                                    rowData.timeZone);

                        }
                        return rowData.trackeeName;

                    }
                },
                {
                    "data" : "firstName",
                    "width" : aColumnWidths[1],
                    "class" : "no-word-break",
                    settings : {
                        source : Global.getDriverSuggestion
                    },
                    "title" : jQuery.i18n.prop("driver.title.txtInfo"),
                    "visible" : Global['show.driver.in.reports'] == 1,
                    "render" : function(value, type, rowData) {
                        return getUserName(rowData.firstName, rowData.lastName);
                    }
                },
                {
                    "data" : "groupName",
                    "width" : aColumnWidths[2],
                    "class" : "no-word-break",
                    "settings" : {
                        source : function(request, oCallback) {
                            oCallback($.ui.autocomplete.filter(Global.aJSTreeGroupItems || [], request.term));
                        }
                    },
```

I make an Ajax call by passing url and get the data in json format, but i want to call a method which has data and pass it to to data table, without making ajax call.

Comment: could you share your code ?

Comment: have you read the documentation for this [jquery data table plugin](https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html)

Comment: I have shared the code @LearningMode.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the document @JaromandaX

Answer (score 7):

You can set custom data by setting `data` option. Examples and usage details are here http://datatables.net/reference/option/data. Set data option as a function which returns preferred array of data.

Comment: Not able to upvote as i dont have enough credits.Thanks @Pranav C Balan.

Comment: Could you also tell how can i update selected rows based on id of that row?

Comment: You can set `columnDefs` option and render output based on data using nested property `render` , https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html